# CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage() working differently on mobile vs desktop

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

In development of my website I've noticed a difference between production on mobile and desktop views. In my website you can crop images(using react-easy-crop) and then it uses drawImage to make a new canvas with the cropped image. On desktop, all works well, but on mobile there are some troubles. Here are some examples: Desktop then mobile. it seems that on mobile the drawimage is replacing the two 0 with pixelCrop.x and pixelCrop.y `ctx.drawImage(image, pixelCrop.x, pixelCrop.y, pixelCrop.width, pixelCrop.height, pixelCrop.x, pixelCrop.y, pixelCrop.width, pixelCrop.height); instead of ctx.drawImage(image, pixelCrop.x, pixelCrop.y, pixelCrop.width, pixelCrop.height, 0, 0, pixelCrop.width, pixelCrop.height );` Has anyone encountered problems like this before? Thanks!

EDIT: this only happens on ios devices!
EDIT-2: found the problem but don't know why its happening. ctx.drawImage looks like this ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight) and for some reason on IOS devices the sx and sy will not draw negative numbers. Once a value goes negative it defaults to 0. This is really annoying and I was wondering who I should contact to get this fixed?

[image: Desktop after crop]

[image: mobile after crop]

Answer (score 0):

Fix it on IOS devices since sx and sy cant be negative the code will look something like this:

```js
if (pixelCrop.x < 0 || pixelCrop.y < 0) {
    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      0,
      0,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height,
      Math.abs((image.width - pixelCrop.width) / 2),
      Math.abs((image.height - pixelCrop.height) / 2),
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height
    );
  } else {
    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      pixelCrop.x,
      pixelCrop.y,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height,
      0,
      0,
      pixelCrop.width,
      pixelCrop.height
    );
```